# problem with Gradient Boosting regression predicting negative values

Tags: regression, machine-learning, boosting

i have data set of which the target values are all positives but when apply Gradient Boosting regression i get some negative predictions but also a good $R^2$ score ($R^2$ = 0.823) but the more confusing part is that if i calculate the $R^2$ based on the absolute values of predictions i get basically the same $R^2$ score with a little improvement ($R^2$ = 0.824).

can anyone explain why this is happening? can i just take absolute of the negatives or replace them with the minimum positive predicted value of model and consider that as the models result?

Comment: How negative are the  negative predictions relative to the spread of the data?  If the actual value is 0.01 and the prediction is -0.01 compared to data which ranges over, say, $[0.01,100]$, then the negative prediction is still extremely accurate - although it could be improved by moving it up to 0 - and would likely contribute essentially nothing to the sum of squared errors, so improving it a little won't alter the $R^2$ significantly.

Comment: i see, well they aren't that close (-1065372.0, 13850.0) but i guess considering the range of the target value they are close enough, so thank you i can understand this part now but still i don't understand why does the model giving negative predictions when there is no negative in the target values?!

Comment: 1. What's the range of the target values?  That negative number looks huge to me, but without scale, I can't judge.  2. Why do you think it wouldn't be able to predict negative values?  After all, the predictions aren't limited to be equal to only observed values of the target variable!

Comment: 1. its roughly between 10000 and 2000000000.  2. i see, i just figured since there is no negative observed value, than the model at least wouldn't predict negative no matter how badly it performs.

Comment: That's true of a random forest but not of most other commonly-used algorithms, like GBMs, or linear regression for that matter.